# make-network-process fails in Emacs 25

Tags: process, networking

`make-network-process` fails on Emacs25 (25.1.50.2 2016-07-03) when loaded with `-q` and `-Q` and trying to eval the following example:

```
(make-network-process
 :name "*server2*"
 :type nil ; stream
 :server t
 :host 'local
 :service t
 :family nil
 :nowait t
 :stop nil
 :noquery t)

;; Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "make server process failed" "Success" :name "*server2*" :type nil :server t :host local :service t :family nil :nowait t :stop nil :noquery t)
;; make-network-process(:name "*server2*" :type nil :server t :host local :service t :family nil :nowait t :stop nil :noquery t)
```

The same example works on Emacs 24.  This same issue is referenced here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38188397/emacs-make-network-process-fails-how-to-debug
- https://github.com/ahungry/geben/issues/4

Is this an Emacs bug?  Is there a workaround?

Comment: Maybe https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=23508

Comment: Is it this exact code that fails, or is it other code immediately after it? This works for me on Emacs 25, but sometimes trying to connect to the server immediately after fails on Emacs 26+ due to increased asynchronicity of the Emacs network code. Geben already made a workaround for this: https://github.com/ahungry/geben/commit/f40a67ffc3d30ca39bfc7984b1f3909590594acc